# VBA copying data from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba, copy

Im just exploring the VBA and trying to use it for copying a selection of data from one workbook to another.
The first book 'send' has information between A:D and the number of rows can change. The 'receiver' will have the information collected from many 'send' so this data needs to be copied in below the last information.
I found this code below and modified it, but it give me a runtime 9 code and falls at
' lMaxRows_t' Any ideas or help much appreciated

```
    Sub CopyData()
Dim sBook_t As String
Dim sBook_s As String
Dim sSheet_t As String
Dim sSheet_s As String
Dim lMaxRows_t As Long
Dim lMaxRows_s As Long
Dim sMaxCol_s As String
Dim sRange_t As String
Dim sRange_s As String
sBook_t = "\\scceastfl5\~\tester receiver.xlsx"
sBook_s = "\\scceastfl5\~\tester send.xlsx"
sSheet_t = "Sheet1"
sSheet_s = "Sheet1"
lMaxRows_t = Workbooks(sBook_t).Sheets(sSheet_t).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lMaxRows_s = Workbooks(sBook_s).Sheets(sSheet_s).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
sMaxCol_s = Workbooks(sBook_s).Sheets(sSheet_s).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Address
sMaxCol_s = Mid(sMaxCol_s, 2, InStr(2, sMaxCol_s, "$") - 2)
If (lMaxRows_t = 1) Then
sRange_t = "A1:" & sMaxCol_s & lMaxRows_s
sRange_s = "A1:" & sMaxCol_s & lMaxRows_s
Workbooks(sBook_t).Sheets(sSheet_t).Range(sRange_t) = Workbooks(sBook_s).Sheets(sSheet_s).Range(sRange_s).Value
Else
sRange_t = "A" & (lMaxRows_t + 1) & ":" & sMaxCol_s & (lMaxRows_t + lMaxRows_s - 1)
sRange_s = "A2:" & sMaxCol_s & lMaxRows_s
Workbooks(sBook_t).Sheets(sSheet_t).Range(sRange_t) = Workbooks(sBook_s).Sheets(sSheet_s).Range(sRange_s).Value
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the error message? Have you tried stepping through your code in debug mode?

Comment: Its a run time error 9 and as i mentioned it falls over at the first line pretty much 'lMaxRows_t '

Comment: This answers neither of my questions above.

Comment: I guess i dont understand your question then.  When i run it in debug mode. it gets up to the cursor when its placed at the '1maxrows' then says error runtime 9.  I thought that was the answer to your two questions....

Comment: 9 is, obviously, the error number. But what's the error *message* or *description*? Who knows what "Error 9" means? Nobody remembers the significance of all error numbers by heart. That's why VBA also tells you what it means. In this case a web search tells me it's "Subscript out of range". Aha. Ok. So either your `sBook_t` subscript or your `sSheet_t` makes no sense. What are their values? You can see that in the debugger. Do these values correspond to what `Workbooks` and `Sheets` expect? Look up VBA help for `Workbooks` and `Sheets`. All this in the spirit of teaching a man to fish...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe like so, this should be easy to edit:

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddToMaster()
'this macro goes IN the master workbook
Dim wsMaster As Worksheet, wbDATA As Workbook
Dim NextRow As Long, LastRow As Long

Set wsMaster = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
NextRow = wsMaster.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Set wbDATA = Workbooks.Open("\\scceastfl5\~\tester send.xlsx")

    With wbDATA.Sheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If LastRow > 19 Then
            .Range("A20:E" & LastRow).Copy
            wsMaster.Range("A" & NextRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            wsMaster.Range("A" & NextRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        End If
    End With

wbDATA.Close False
End Sub
```

This version goes in the SENDER workbook:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SendToMaster()
'this macro goes IN the sender workbook
Dim wsSEND As Worksheet, wbMASTER As Workbook
Dim NextRow As Long, LastRow As Long

Set wsSEND = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = wsSEND.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set wbMASTER = Workbooks.Open("\\scceastfl5\~\tester receiver.xlsx")

    With wbMASTER.Sheets("Sheet1")
        NextRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        wsSEND.Range("A20:E" & LastRow).Copy
        .Range("A" & NextRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Range("A" & NextRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End With

wbMASTER.Close True     'save and close the master

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  Just one issue with this, the macro need to be run from the 'sender' form as the user wont have access to the master.  Its the user that uses the sender to update the 'master' daily.  But other than that i think you added really useful stuff.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook

'Set workbooks
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("c:\Path\of\your\file.xlsx")
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("c:\Path\of\your\file1.xlsx")

'clear all data
wb2.Sheets(1).Cells.Clear

'Copy data from wb1 sheet 1 to sheet 1 in wb2
With wb1.Sheets(1)
    .UsedRange.Copy wb2.Sheets(1).range("A1").end(xldown).offset(1,0)
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry before maybe i didnt explain enough.  I have lots of 'forms' that contain data in column A:E and from row 20:?? where ?? can vary between 1-100.  This information needs to go from this workbook to the 'master' each night.  But the rows cannot replace information in the master hence it has to be copied in the line under the last line- if that makes sense.

Comment: Still got that "Clear" in there.

Comment: yea isn't that going to clear it all?and when i paste the data into the 'master it all need to be under one another.  So like a master list with all the separate workbook informations

Comment: also its only some of the data off 'wb 1' not the whole sheet