# copying data from one workbook to another workbook with a table

Tags: excel, vba

Hi there i am new to forum and need a little help, I have been trying to copy data from one workbook to master workbook which contain tables where copied data should go.I have a post in another excel forum here, http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/977613-copy-data-from-changing-range-in-on-workbook-to-another.html

but the code doesnt work properly and no matter what i try i cant figure it out, but the other day  i came across a post here that the code given in the answer is just about perfect the post is located here [VBA copying data from one workbook to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329697/vba-copying-data-from-one-workbook-to-another?newreg=1046a6d40e984041872187c4f001754a)

this work just about perfect only 2 small problems with it that i cant get to work

1. i cant get the data that is copied over to the master to go into row 2 its like the code thinks there is data there because its a table?
2. i cant get master to save and close

see code below I hope i put code in properly and not broke any forum rules

Thanks for any help

```
    Sub SendToMaster()
    'this macro goes IN the sender workbook
    Dim wsSEND As Worksheet
    Dim wbMASTER As Workbook
    Dim NextRow As Long, LastRow As Long

    Set wsSEND = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("january")
    LastRow = wsSEND.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set wbMASTER = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\Ian\My Documents\excel\Disk_Inventory_V3_master.xlsm")

        With wbMASTER.Sheets("january")
            NextRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            wsSEND.Range("A2:E" & LastRow).Copy
            .Range("A" & NextRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Range("A" & NextRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        End With

        wsSEND.Range("A2:E200").ClearContents
        ThisWorkbook.Save
        ThisWorkbook.Close


        wbMASTER.Close True
         'save and close the master

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. :) Just to be clear, is the table you're referring to a "named table", ie. created by `Format as Table` from Ribbon?

Comment: oops sorry for the mistake in replying with answer instead of comments used my cell phone last nite to reply :( so to reply properly Yes it is a named table created by format and you can see in ribbon. The name of the table is the same as the page name january

Comment: ok i figured out how to get the master workbook to save and close, I still cant get the data copied over to start at row 2 anybody??

Comment: still cant figure it out anybody ??

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a named table created by format and you can see in ribbon. The name of the table is the same as the page name january

Comment: you can add comment on your question. Do not post it as answer:). And welcome to SO.